# SELECT last 250 rows from a table with no auto id

Tags: mysql, select, sql-order-by, limit

I know there is a few posts out there already but some are conflicting.

I have taken on a project in which I have inherited a table with a few 1000 entries.

The problem is, there is no auto increment ID field on the table and I have been asked to extract the last 300 rows that were entered into it.

It it possible to extract the last 300 entries from a table? Is there a "systems row id"?

Comment: Can you show us your table schema please :) ?

Comment: Does the table contain a column that records the time at which each record was inserted?

Comment: No the field names are as follows:  attri, gnumber, onumber, com, type, gen  There is no timestamp, AI field or no other means of differentiating between the rows...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT col1, col2, ... 
FROM (SELECT col1,col2, ..., (@auto:=@auto+1) indx 
      FROM tablename, (SELECT @auto:=1) AS a
     ) AS b 
ORDER BY indx DESC 
LIMIT 30
```

Comment: When I run this in phpmyadmin, the results are returned but there a few errors... "unknown table status: TABLE_TYPE" is this due to mysql creating some temporary tables then removing them?

Answer (score 2):

The strict answer is "no" unless you have a date or something else that indicates order.  Tables are inherently unordered.

In practice, you generally fetch the data back in the order you put it in.  The more true the statement, "I loaded the data once, with no subsequent inserts, into a system with only one processor and one disk", the more likely that the data is actually in order.

Having a system row id would not help you, because you might have deletes and subsequent inserts.  A later record would be put in an earlier page, in this case.

You have a small table.  Do a `select *`, copy the data into a spreadsheet and do the work from there.

Alternatively, you can select the table with an increasing row number, insert into another table, and then do the select from there.  Something like this pseudocode:

```
insert into NewTable (seqnum, cols)
    select :rownum=:rownum+1, cols
    from YourTable
```

There is a chance you'll get what you want.

One last point.  *If* you did inserts and have the log files since the inserts, you might be able to get the information from there.  With a little work.

Comment: +1 for copy the data into a spreadsheet and do the work from there

Comment: Just about what I was going to post, but one other important point to add here - if any records were ever deleted from the table, all bets are off as to the ordering (as MySQL will fill the gaps left by deleted rows with newly inserted ones)

Comment: I knew I had heard of the existence of a rownum somewhere before.. thanks. The table I am working with has had 300+ rows entered in a block, the table was not touched after the rows were entered.. this and Saharsh Shah's answer have helped massively, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you at least have a record insertion time in the table, then you can use this.. Otherwise no.

```
SELECT * FROM 
yourtable 
ORDER BY inserted_time desc limit 300;
```